# Validation error: Extending Gutenberg gallery block

Tags: plugins, errors, gallery, validation, block-editor

I am trying to extend the Gutenberg `core/gallery` block to add some new functionality to my image gallery on the frontend. I have created a separate plugin to handle this task.
I have registered my script with the following code:

```
function mt_enqueue_gutenberg(){

  wp_enqueue_script(
        'mt-gallery-block',
        plugins_url( 'gallery-block.js',__FILE__),
        array( 'wp-blocks', 'wp-i18n', 'wp-element' )
    );

    //Script and stylesheet loaded on frontend only
    if(!is_admin()){
      wp_enqueue_script(
        'mt-gallery-frontend-script',
        plugins_url( 'gallery.js', __FILE__),
        array( 'mt-gallery-block' )
      );

      wp_enqueue_style(
        'mt-gallery-frontend-style',
        plugins_url( 'gallery.css', __FILE__),
        array( 'mt-gallery-block' )
      );
    }
}

add_action( 'enqueue_block_editor_assets', 'mt_enqueue_gutenberg');
```

In my `gallery-block.js` file I am using the `blocks.getSaveElement` filter to edit the block’s `HTML`-output to the frontend.

```
//Filter hook
wp.hooks.addFilter(
    'blocks.getSaveElement',
    'wpse-298225',
    mt_gallerySaveElement
)

function mt_gallerySaveElement( element, blockType, attributes ) {
    //returns the element without changing it, if it is not the gallery block
    if ( blockType.name !== 'core/gallery' ) {
        return element;
    }

    //Creates div element with nested img's
    var newElement = wp.element.createElement(
        'div',
        {
            'className': 'gallery-grid',
            'data-total-slides': attributes.images.length
        },
        //Loops through each image in the gallery and creates an img-element
        attributes.images.map(
            function( image, index ) {
              return wp.element.createElement(
                        'img',
                        {
                            'src': image.url,
                            'alt': image.alt,
                            'className': 'gallery-item',
                            'data-slide-no': index,
                            'data-caption': image.caption[0]
                        }
                    )

              }

        )
    )

    return newElement
}
```

Everything works as it is supposed to except when I reload the Gutenberg editor. When I reload the page I get a validation error and I am not allowed to edit the gallery block. (See screenshots below)

[image: Gallery block - before and after reload]

Below I have provided a screenshot of the console log after I reloaded the page:

[image: Validation error - console log]

I am pretty sure the error occurs because my output does not correspond to the expected structure of the gallery, and thus WordPress does not see any images inside the gallery block when I reload the page.

**So, my question is: How can I fix this validation error?**

**Assuming the error is caused by the difference between my `HTML` structure and the expected gallery structure: How can I make Gutenberg recognize my `HTML` structure as a gallery?**

Any suggestions would be highly appreciated.

Comment: This is expected behavior - if you modify the HTML of a block, it won't be recognized as the original block. Rather than trying to manipulate a core block it seems like unregistering the core block and registering a new replacement block in its place would be a safer approach - that way you're ensuring users of the site use your particular customized gallery, which will validate because it defines its own HTML structure.

Comment: Thanks for your code! I was getting crazy about extending the gallery and this saved me some time coding it myself! One small addition: instead of using the <kbd>ctrl</kbd> or <kbd>cmd</kbd> button to select multiple images you could set the following prop: ``gallery={true)`` which will enable the same selectable gallery in the media pop up as with the gutenberg gallery block.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**Answering my own question:**

As suggested by [WebElaine](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/102815/webelaine) I created a completely new block to fix the problem. 
To make this task easier, I used [create-guten-block by Ahmad Awais](https://github.com/ahmadawais/create-guten-block), which is pretty easy to set up.

In init.php I made sure to enqueue my JavaScript and extra CSS for the frontend. This should be straight forward. I recommend reading the [Learning Gutenberg series on css-tricks.com](https://css-tricks.com/learning-gutenberg-1-series-intro/). It was a great help for me getting started.

The important part is how I created the gallery block. In block.js (created by create-guten-block) I have destructured `MediaUpload` from `wp.editor`, and `Button` from `wp.components`.

```
const { MediaUpload } = wp.editor; //Import MediaUpload from wp.editor
const { Button } = wp.components; //Import Button from wp.components
```

I register the block with a title, an icon, a category, some keywords and an images attribute with the type array. This will contain the images from the gallery

```
 registerBlockType( 'cgb/block-my-test-block', {
    title: __( 'MT - Gallery' ), // Block title.
    icon: 'format-gallery', // Block icon from Dashicons → https://developer.wordpress.org/resource/dashicons/.
    category: 'common', // Block category
    keywords: [ //Keywords
        __('materialtheme'),
        __('photos'),
        __('images')
    ],
    attributes: { //Attributes
        images : { //Images array
            type: 'array',
        }
},
```

My edit function (the part of the block shown in the editor) looks like this:

```
edit({ attributes, className, setAttributes }) {

        //Destructuring the images array attribute
        const {images = []} = attributes;


        // This removes an image from the gallery
        const removeImage = (removeImage) => {
                    //filter the images
                    const newImages = images.filter( (image) => {
                        //If the current image is equal to removeImage the image will be returnd
                        if(image.id != removeImage.id) {
                            return image;
                        }
                    });

                    //Saves the new state
                    setAttributes({
                        images:newImages,
                    })
        }


        //Displays the images
        const displayImages = (images) => {
            return (
                //Loops throug the images
                images.map( (image) => {
                    return (
                    <div className="gallery-item-container">
                            <img className='gallery-item' src={image.url} key={ images.id } />
                            <div className='remove-item' onClick={() => removeImage(image)}><span class="dashicons dashicons-trash"></span></div>
                            <div className='caption-text'>{image.caption[0]}</div>
                    </div>
                    )
                })

            )
        }

        //JSX to return
        return (
            <div>
                <div className="gallery-grid">
                    {displayImages(images)}
                </div>
                <br/>
                <MediaUpload
                        onSelect={(media) => {setAttributes({images: [...images, ...media]});}}
                        type="image"
                        multiple={true}
                        value={images}
                        render={({open}) => (
                            <Button className="select-images-button is-button is-default is-large" onClick={open}>
                                Add images
                            </Button>
                        )}
                    />
            </div>

        );
    },
```

Here I make use of the `MediaUpload` and `Button` object.
Notice that I have set `multiple` to `true`, which allows me to select multiple images.  To select multiple images this way, you must hold down <kbd>CTRL</kbd> like you would do selecting multiple files in File Explorer (on Windows).

In my save function I map the images and add the desired attributes to the `img`-tag.

```
save({attributes}) {
    //Destructuring the images array attribute
    const { images = [] } = attributes;

    // Displays the images
    const displayImages = (images) => {
        return (
            images.map( (image,index) => {
                return (
                        <img
                            className='gallery-item'
                            key={images.id}
                            src={image.url}
                            data-slide-no={index}
                            data-caption={image.caption[0]}
                            alt={image.alt}
                            />
                )
            })
        )
    }

    //JSX to return
    return (
        <div>
        <div className="gallery-grid" data-total-slides={images.length}>{ displayImages(images) }</div>
        </div>
    );

},
```

My complete code from block.js looks like this:

```
/**
 * BLOCK: my-test-block
 *
 * Registering a basic block with Gutenberg.
 * Simple block, renders and saves the same content without any interactivity.
 */

import './style.scss';
import './editor.scss';

const { __ } = wp.i18n; // Import __() from wp.i18n
const { registerBlockType } = wp.blocks; // Import registerBlockType() from wp.blocks
const { MediaUpload } = wp.editor; //Import MediaUpload from wp.editor
const { Button } = wp.components; //Import Button from wp.components


/**
 * Register: aa Gutenberg Block.
 *
 * Registers a new block provided a unique name and an object defining its
 * behavior. Once registered, the block is made editor as an option to any
 * editor interface where blocks are implemented.
 *
 * @link https://wordpress.org/gutenberg/handbook/block-api/
 * @param  {string}   name     Block name.
 * @param  {Object}   settings Block settings.
 * @return {?WPBlock}          The block, if it has been successfully
 *                             registered; otherwise `undefined`.
 */

registerBlockType( 'cgb/block-my-test-block', {
    title: __( 'MT - Gallery' ), // Block title.
    icon: 'format-gallery', // Block icon from Dashicons → https://developer.wordpress.org/resource/dashicons/.
    category: 'common', // Block category
    keywords: [ //Keywords
        __('materialtheme'),
        __('photos'),
        __('images')
    ],
    attributes: { //Attributes
        images : { //Images array
            type: 'array',
        }
},

    /**
     * The edit function describes the structure of your block in the context of the editor.
     * This represents what the editor will render when the block is used.
     *
     * The "edit" property must be a valid function.
     *
     * @link https://wordpress.org/gutenberg/handbook/block-api/block-edit-save/
     */
    edit({ attributes, className, setAttributes }) {

        //Destructuring the images array attribute
        const {images = []} = attributes;


        // This removes an image from the gallery
        const removeImage = (removeImage) => {
                    //filter the images
                    const newImages = images.filter( (image) => {
                        //If the current image is equal to removeImage the image will be returnd
                        if(image.id != removeImage.id) {
                            return image;
                        }
                    });

                    //Saves the new state
                    setAttributes({
                        images:newImages,
                    })
        }


        //Displays the images
        const displayImages = (images) => {
            return (
                //Loops throug the images
                images.map( (image) => {
                    return (
                    <div className="gallery-item-container">
                            <img className='gallery-item' src={image.url} key={ images.id } />
                            <div className='remove-item' onClick={() => removeImage(image)}><span class="dashicons dashicons-trash"></span></div>
                            <div className='caption-text'>{image.caption[0]}</div>
                    </div>
                    )
                })

            )
        }

        //JSX to return
        return (
            <div>
                <div className="gallery-grid">
                    {displayImages(images)}
                </div>
                <br/>
                <MediaUpload
                        onSelect={(media) => {setAttributes({images: [...images, ...media]});}}
                        type="image"
                        multiple={true}
                        value={images}
                        render={({open}) => (
                            <Button className="select-images-button is-button is-default is-large" onClick={open}>
                                Add images
                            </Button>
                        )}
                    />
            </div>

        );
    },

    /**
     * The save function defines the way in which the different attributes should be combined
     * into the final markup, which is then serialized by Gutenberg into post_content.
     *
     * The "save" property must be specified and must be a valid function.
     *
     * @link https://wordpress.org/gutenberg/handbook/block-api/block-edit-save/
     */
    save({attributes}) {
        //Destructuring the images array attribute
        const { images = [] } = attributes;

        // Displays the images
        const displayImages = (images) => {
            return (
                images.map( (image,index) => {
                    return (
                            <img
                                className='gallery-item'
                                key={images.id}
                                src={image.url}
                                data-slide-no={index}
                                data-caption={image.caption[0]}
                                alt={image.alt}
                                />
                    )
                })
            )
        }

        //JSX to return
        return (
            <div>
            <div className="gallery-grid" data-total-slides={images.length}>{ displayImages(images) }</div>
            </div>
        );

    },
} );
```

After adding some styling my gallery looks like this in the editor:

[image]

Comment: Hi @Andreas would you ming sharing your stylesheet for this block too?  Thanks, mate for the great share

Answer (score 1):

2 years later https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/313969/102683 is still the ultimate answer.

UPDATING with the new way to import the WordPress components.

```
import { __ } from '@wordpress/i18n';
import { MediaUpload } from '@wordpress/block-editor';
import { Button } from '@wordpress/components';
import { registerBlockType } from '@wordpress/blocks';
```