# what is the purpose of the namespace argument when customizing blocks?

Tags: javascript, block-editor

I'm trying to customize the Gallery block using the new Gutenberk Block API thing.

Long story short, I need to [add a filter](https://wordpress.org/gutenberg/handbook/designers-developers/developers/filters/block-filters/) to do the customization.

So what is the purpose of the namespace argument when calling the `addFilter` function? I am failing to find an explanation for the purpose of this argument.

**Edit:** Essentially, I am trying to do what is shown in [this post/question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/313795/validation-error-extending-gutenberg-gallery-block?rq=1). Still, the question remains, what is the purpose of the namespace argument, and its role in the scope of the project?

Ref: [Validation error: Extending Gutenberg gallery block](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/313795/validation-error-extending-gutenberg-gallery-block?rq=1)

Also, if you're going to downvote, can you explain why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So what is the purpose of the namespace argument when calling the
>   addFilter function? I am failing to find an explanation for the
>   purpose of this argument.

The core ticket for adding Javascript actions and filters is [#21170](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/21170)

It spans many years and contains a lot of discussions about e.g. *namespacing*.

See e.g. this [comment](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/21170#comment:32) by @azaozz:

> Also thinking the namespaces/identifiers should be required as that
>   would make removing anonymous functions easy. As far as I see the most
>   common use of this would be with anonymous functions

and then it gets implemented e.g. [here](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/21170#comment:144) by @adamsilverstein and then with more iterations.

[Here's](https://www.ibenic.com/use-wordpress-hooks-package-javascript-apps) another description by Igor Benić:

> That difference is the namespace which you also add when adding
>   actions and filters (or removing them). This is done in case you have
>   same function names under different components (or Apps). With using
>   namespaces you can easily distinguish to which component or app it
>   belongs so you don’t accidentaly remove the wrong function.