# Custom Gallery Block - Uncaught TypeError: setAttributes is not a function

Tags: block-editor, gallery

I tried building my own custom gallery gutenberg block as shown [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/313969/230299) to get more familiar with the block structure.
Putting all the code into a single file works fine, but when I try to split it up in edit.js and save.js, it returns this error upon trying to add images to it: "Uncaught TypeError: setAttributes is not a function"

I wasn't able to resolve this, what's the issue?

attributes in block.json

```
"attributes": {
        "images" : {
            "type": "array" 
        }
},
```

edit.js

```
/**
 * Retrieves the translation of text.
 *
 * @see https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/packages/packages-i18n/
 */
import { __ } from '@wordpress/i18n';

/**
 * React hook that is used to mark the block wrapper element.
 * It provides all the necessary props like the class name.
 *
 * @see https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/packages/packages-block-editor/#useblockprops
 */
import { 
    useBlockProps,
    MediaUpload
 } from '@wordpress/block-editor';

import {
    Button
} from '@wordpress/components';

//import {registerBlockType} from "@wordpress/blocks";
/**
 * Lets webpack process CSS, SASS or SCSS files referenced in JavaScript files.
 * Those files can contain any CSS code that gets applied to the editor.
 *
 * @see https://www.npmjs.com/package/@wordpress/scripts#using-css
 */
import './editor.scss';



/**
 * The edit function describes the structure of your block in the context of the
 * editor. This represents what the editor will render when the block is used.
 *
 * @see https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/block-api/block-edit-save/#edit
 *
 * @return {WPElement} Element to render.
 */
export default function Edit(attributes, className, setAttributes) {

    const blockProps = useBlockProps();

    // Getting the images of the array
    const {images = [] } = attributes;

    // to remove image from gallery
    const removeImage = (removeImage) => {
        //filter images 
        const newImages = images.filter( (image) => {
            // if current image is equal to removeImage, image will be returend
            if(image.id != removeImage.id) {
                return image;
            }
        });
        //save new state
        setAttributes({
            images: newImages,
        })
    }

    //Display the images
    const displayImages = (images) => {
        return (
            //Loop through images 
            images.map((image) => {
                return (
                    <div className="gallery-item-container">
                        <img className='gallery-item' src={image.url} key={ images.id } />
                        <div className='remove-item' onClick={() => removeImage(image)}><span class="dashicons dashicons-trash"></span></div>
                        <div className='caption-text'>{image.caption[0]}</div>
                    </div>
                )
            })
        )
    }
    
    //JSX to return
    return (
        <>
        <div {...blockProps}>
            <div className='gallery-grid'>
                {displayImages(images)}
            </div>

            <br/>

            <MediaUpload 
                onSelect={(media) => setAttributes({
                    images: [...images,...media],
                })
                    
                }
                type="image"
                multiple={true}
                gallery={true}
                value={images}
                render={({open}) => (
                    <Button className="select-images-button is-button is-default is-large" onClick={open}>
                        Add images
                    </Button>
                )}
            />
        </div>
        </>
    );
}
```

Comment: are you sure you want to use `(attributes, className, setAttributes)` for your function arguments? This is very weird, and not what the examples show, I've never seen an example that didn't use `{}` to destructure the props

Comment: also note that using array type block attributes like this will make things difficult, it's much much easier to use a child block for each item in a gallery, and you get controls for reordering items and removing/duplicating them for free. It also means your items show up in the outliner controls, and you avoid a large number of easy to make mistakes and difficult problems. Making block variants and block styles of the default gallery is even easier though

Comment: Oh my god, I feel so stupid now, somehow I didn't see that... Thank you! @TomJNowell 
And that's an interesting point with the child blocks, I will look into that!

Comment: I spent 2 days trying to debug a `useState` call before realising I'd used `{}` instead of `[]` it happens to the best of us

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried:

```js
export default function Edit( { attributes, className, setAttributes } ) {
```

`Edit` is a react component, and react components receive props, so `Edit( props )` is more accurate, hence the `{}` in the examples