# Gutenberg gallery hook errors

Tags: hooks, block-editor

I try to modify the gallery block of Gutenberg and I use the following snippet

```
export function defaultColumnsNumber( attributes ) {
    console.log(attributes.images.length)
    return Math.min( 3, attributes.images.length );
}

function modifyGalleryMarkup( element, blockType, attributes ) {

    if ( blockType.name !== 'core/gallery' ) {
        return element;
    }

    const { images, columns = defaultColumnsNumber( attributes ), imageCrop, linkTo } = attributes;

    console.log(attributes)
    var newElement = wp.element.createElement(
        'ul',
        {
            'className': `lightbox columns-${ columns } ${ imageCrop ? 'is-cropped' : '' }`,
        },
        attributes.images.map(
            function( image ) {
                return wp.element.createElement(
                    'li',
                    {
                        'className': 'blocks-gallery-item my-gallery-item',
                    },
                    wp.element.createElement(
                        'img',
                        {
                            'src': image.url,
                        }
                    )
                )
            }
        )
    )

    return newElement
}

wp.hooks.addFilter(
    'blocks.getSaveElement',
    'plugin/modify-gallery',
    modifyGalleryMarkup
);
```

I can save it but on page reload I get the following error in console

```
Block validation failed for `core/gallery`

Expected:

<ul class="lightbox columns-0 is-cropped"></ul>

Actual:

<ul class="lightbox columns-3 is-cropped">< ....
```

what I'm missing in my snippet?

Answer (score 1):

Seems that when you modify the existing block's HTML, then it is no longer being validated.
Instead, you might try to create your own block. Look here is [a good approach](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/313795/validation-error-extending-gutenberg-gallery-block) and [here too](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/298225/how-to-extend-the-gallery-block-in-gutenberg).

Comment: I made a custom gallery block based on the source code, but taking a consideration the effort I would say it is bit too much. Would be great to can modify some markup attributes on the flow of the core blocks.